# Chdir doesn't affect on require in php

Tags: php, apache

Why chdir() in php doesn't affect on require ?

```
folder/
   index.php   // first index
index.php      // second index
```

code of first index is

```
var_dump(getcwd()); // /var/www/html/project/folder
chdir('..');
var_dump(getcwd()); // /var/www/html/project
require 'index.php';
```

It will be recursion error, because first index call himself. I know about possibility to change require to require '../index.php'; but it should be work with chdir().
I gues it is php.ini or apache problem, cant google it.

php 5.5

Comment: Thread Safety is enabled

Comment: What is the value of the include_path? if you specify a relative path it'll ignore the include_path value which is why that would work.  include_path usually has "." in it thus it will load the `index.php` in your current directory.

Comment: It's work on my local machine, but doesn't work on colleague machine.

Comment: `chdir` Returns true on success or false on failure. Might be worth checking which one it is when running such a recursion-prone script.

Comment: @apokryfos fix question. chdir is success

Comment: The test code you've shown. Are you testing that via the CLI?

Comment: @GerardRoche no, its common web mode

Comment: Put the following at the top of `folder/index.php`: `if (isset($x)) {exit("RECURSION!\n");}
$x=1;
echo ini_get('include_path')."\n";
echo getcwd()."\n";
chdir('..');
echo getcwd()."\n";
require 'index.php';` and show the output.